# How to test a web scraping application?

Tags: ruby, testing, nokogiri

I am using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) to check that an automatically generated site has the correct information and sub sites. It works, but I need to test it, and I'm not sure of a good way to do so. My current approach is to find a site online that I know has certain information, and make sure that the application finds that.

So, for example, I visually check to see how many rows there are in a table on the site, and then test to see if the function that checks that table returns that number of rows. Both the URL and the number are hardcoded. The site will probably not change, but it is not impossible either, in which case the tests will obviously fail.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: A better tool to check for correctness would be [Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize). It's based on Nokogiri, but has lots of pre-built methods to tell you about the elements of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create some HTML pages and open them with your Nokigiri-based Object and validate your assumptions

```
# fixture.html
# ... truncated
<table>
  <tr></td>One Row</td></tr>
</table>

class TableScraper
   attr_accessor :document, parser
   def initialize(document, parser)
     @document = document
     @parser   = parser
   end
   def rows_in_table
     # your code here
   end
end

describe TableScraper do
  let(:file) { File.open("/path/to/fixture.html") }
  subject { described_class.new(file, Nokogiri::HTML) }
  it { expect { subject.rows_in_table }.to eq 1 }
end
```

Obviously this is a simple example and not real code, but this is how I would approach it.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was trying to avoid having to make a bunch of test sites.

Comment: You can automate the creation of the test fixtures with tools like [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr). It requires a little configuration, but on the plus side, you can delete the fixtures every once in awhile and check whether your code still works.